# Renaming Description of snapshot vmware using powercli (powershell)

Tags: vmware, snapshot, powershell-4.0, powercli

I was trying to edit the description field of all snaps present in vcenter. The script is able to find the snaps properly and its trying to edit the same, i could see the task as renaming snapshot, but not reflecting the change actually. Can some somebody help me resolve this.. ? Thanks in advance.

```
   Get-Module -Name VMware* -ListAvailable | Import-Module
$AllSnaps = @()
$User = "Domain\UserName"
$File = "Credentials.txt"
$MyCredential=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)

foreach ($VC in $VCServers) {

$Stat = connect-viserver $VC -credential $MyCredential -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
     if($Stat.IsConnected){
            write-host "Connected to VC - $VC"
            $AllSnaps = Get-VM  | Get-Snapshot | select VM, Name, Description
                 ForEach ($Snap in $AllSnaps)  {
                      If ($($Snap.Name) -Match "NBU_SNAPSHOT" -or $($Snap.Description) -Match "PERM-") {
                      Write-host "No Action required in these VM's"
                      } else { 
                      $NewDesc = "PERM-"+$($Snap.description)
                      get-vm -name $($snap.vm) | get-snapshot -name $($Snap.name) | set-snapshot -description $NewDesc
                      }
                  }
disconnect-viserver -Server $VC -Force -confirm:$False
}
}
```

Comment: nobody online just to give a light on it ?

Comment: Hey stackoverflow.... Any help ?

Comment: Get-VM  | Get-Snapshot | Where {$_.Name -notmatch "NBU_SNAPSHOT" -and $_.description -notmatch "PERM" } | set-snapshot -description ("PERM" + $_.description) | select vm, name, description


VM     Name Description
--     ---- -----------
PDRSQ01 test PERM
PDRVC01 test PERM
PDMI... S... PERM
SRMAPP3 S... PERM
MPDMD... C.. PERM
MPDMD... S.. PERM
PRMAPP4 S... PERM
VMUDMI... S. PERM
DDMA... S... PERM
MPDMD... S...PERM
PSPWTE... C. PERM
MUMYS... V.. PERM

I need to get the "PERM + Old description" as output , How to do it ?

Comment: `code`Get-VM  | Get-Snapshot | Where {$_.Name -notmatch "NBU_SNAPSHOT" -and $_.description -notmatch "PERM" } | set-snapshot -description ("PERM" + $_.description) | select vm, name, description`code`


VM     Name Description
--     ---- -----------
PDRSQ01 test PERM
PDRVC01 test PERM
PDMI... S... PERM
SRMAPP3 S... PERM
MPDMD... C.. PERM
MPDMD... S.. PERM
PRMAPP4 S... PERM
VMUDMI... S. PERM
DDMA... S... PERM
MPDMD... S...PERM
PSPWTE... C. PERM
MUMYS... V.. PERM

I need to get the "PERM + Old description" as output , How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($snap in $AllSnaps){get-vm -name $snap.vm | get-snapshot -name 
$Snap.name | set-snapshot -description "blah"}
```

Remove the brackets works.

Then the answer might appear as not set as you have to re-get $AllSnaps